# Limit with L'Hopital's rule - work checking

Tags: limits, proof-verification

I am taking this limit:

$$\lim_{x\to\pi/4}{10(\tan(x))^{\tan(2x)}}$$

Attempted the following:

$$\lim_{x\to\pi/4}{e^{\ln(10)+\tan(2x)\times\ln(\tan(x))}}$$

Consider exponents:

$$\lim_{x\to\pi/4}{\ln(10)+\tan(2x)\times\ln(\tan(x))}$$

$$\ln(10) + \lim_{x\to\pi/4}{\tan(2x)\times\ln(\tan(x))}$$

$$\ln(10) + \lim_{x\to\pi/4}{\frac{\ln(\tan(x))}{(\tan(2x))^{-1}}}$$

l'Hopital's $$\ln(10) + \lim_{x\to\pi/4}{0.5\frac{\csc(x)\sec(x)}{\tan(x)+x\sec^2(x)}}\tag{*}$$

$$\ln(10) + \frac{1}{1+\pi/2}$$

Apply result as exponent of $e$:

$$e^{\ln(10) + \frac{1}{1+\pi/2}}$$

$$10e^{\frac{1}{1+\pi/2}}$$

This result is incorrect. Where did I err?

Comment: This sort of question is why we need a  <solution-verification> tag.  The added tag should read "solution verification".  (You haven't done anything wrong, Luna.  I'm addressing the fact that the site (MSE) currently has no appropriate tag to use for solution verifications.)

Comment: Check your l'Hopital step.

Answer (score 1):

The denominator in (*) looks strange to me. It should be the derivative of $(\tan(2x))^{-1}=\cot(2x)=\frac{\cos(2x)}{\sin(2x)}$ which is
$$
2\frac{-\sin^2(2x)-\cos^2(2x)}{\sin^2(2x)}=-\frac{2}{\sin^2(2x)}.
$$
Where did you get the factor $x$ from?

P.S. It is easier to split $\tan(2x)$ as
$$
\lim_{x\to\pi/4}{\frac{\ln(\tan(x))}{(\tan(2x))^{-1}}}=\lim_{x\to\pi/4}{\underbrace{\sin(2x)}_{\to 1}\cdot\frac{\ln(\tan(x))}{\cos(2x)}}=\lim_{x\to\pi/4}{\frac{\ln(\tan(x))}{\cos(2x)}}
$$
and then apply L'Hospital's rule.